# Microsoft.VC90.DebugMFC assembly not installed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vcredist

I am trying to run a certain application but when i get the following error whilel loading a dll:

"*Windows API LoadLibraryEx returened error # 14001 ( 0x36B1)..."*

I opened windows event viewer and got this error:

*Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.DebugMFC could not be found and Last Error was The referenced assembly is not installed on your system.*

My question is, what is Microsoft.VC90.DebugMFC ?

Comment: It seems the application uses MFC and is built in Debug configuration. While `Microsoft.VC90.MFC` is a redistributable component (part of the Visual C++ runtime), the debug version is not.

Comment: So what can i do?

Comment: Build the Release version of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Visual studio professional 2008 SP1 solved the problem